# What is PRAGMA EXCEPTION equivalent in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

How to implement the pragma exception_init for postgresql.
Here writing the code for oracle which I want to migrate to postgresql, I want to user defined exceptions or error codes instead of PostgreSQL Error Codes.

```
    declare
        not_dropable exception;
            pragma exception_init (not_dropable, -942);      
    begin

    execute immediate 'drop table    &t' ;

    exception
       when not_dropable then
            dbms_output.put_line ( 'Table &t  does not exist ' );
    end;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct equivalent in Postgres.

The only option you have is to check for the [error code](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html). A non existing table is reported with the SQLSTATE `42P01` or the name `undefined_object`

The equivalent would be something like this:

```
do
$$
declare
  l_tablename text := '....';
begin
  execute format('drop table %I', l_tablename);
exception 
  when undefined_object then 
     raise notice 'Table % does not exist', l_tablename;
end;
$$
```

Alternatively you can check for the error code directly `when sqlstate '42704' then ...`